# How to resolve "multiple matching crates for `package`" in cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-crates, rust-cargo

When running `cargo build`:

```
error: multiple matching crates for `url`
```

It then lists the candidates:

- `./target/deps/liburl-11a95471847b9e04.rlib`
- `/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liburl-4e7c5e5c.{so,rlib}`

... and then aborts because it cannot decide which one.

```
src/http/lib.rs:18:1: 18:18 error: can't find crate for `url`
src/http/lib.rs:18 extern crate url;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

How to work around this, or fix this problem?

---

NOTE:

This [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15874)
and this [commit](https://github.com/servo/rust-url/commit/092c4e65031215b6a8116411898636c4834c39fa)
appear to be related to the problem, from the comments:

```
+//! rust-url’s crate is also named `url`.
+//! Cargo will automatically resolve the name conflict,
+//! but that means that you can not also use the old `url` in the same crate.
```

---

Installation specifics:

```
$ rustc -v
rustc 0.12.0-pre-nightly (7a25cf3f3 2014-07-30 17:06:18 +0000)
$ cargo -V
0.0.1-pre-nightly (4a69ffa 2014-07-29 21:30:40 +0000)
```

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]

name = "nickel-demo"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [ "your-name@gmail.com" ]

[[bin]]

name = "nickel-demo"
path = "src/main.rs"

[dependencies.nickel]

git = "https://github.com/nickel-org/nickel.rs.git"

[dependencies.rust-postgres]

git = "https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres.git"
```

(copied from http://nickel.rs/getting-started.html and added one extra dependency)

The full error that I get is this:

```
   Compiling rust-postgres v0.0.0 (https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres.git#7d842441)
Build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
Could not compile `rust-postgres`.

--- stderr
src/lib.rs:70:1: 70:18 error: multiple matching crates for `url`
src/lib.rs:70 extern crate url;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: candidates:
note: path: /usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liburl-4e7c5e5c.so
note: path: /usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liburl-4e7c5e5c.rlib
note: crate name: url
note: path: /home/bojangle/k/nickel-demo/target/deps/liburl-11a95471847b9e04.rlib
note: crate name: url
src/lib.rs:70:1: 70:18 error: can't find crate for `url`
src/lib.rs:70 extern crate url;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors


To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Comment: What is your `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: @dbaupp Added the toml file to the question.

Comment: That happens because the Nickel depends on the `github.com/servo/rust-url` while the Postgres uses the stock old `url`, AFAIK. Might be a Cargo problem in that it doesn't treat the dependencies on a per unit basis.

Answer (score 1):

Now (today's version of Cargo) it also gives this error during fetching packages:

```
native library `openssl` is being linked to by more than one package, and can only be linked to by one package

  openssl-sys v0.2.13 (https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl.git#2f5d1e57)
  openssl-sys v0.2.15
```

All you can do in both cases it's repoint one of your dependencies to the same transitive dependency by changing their `Cargo.toml` right inside the cloned rustlib or nickel (or curl-rust in openssl-sys case) and repoint your `Cargo.toml` to the changed one: http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#overriding-build-scripts, so it's just one line inside your .cargo/config:

```
 paths = ["/path/to/overridden/dependency"]
```

And something like that in /path/to/overridden/dependency/Cargo.toml:

```
 [dependencies]
 transitive-dependency-name = "choosed-version"
```

You could point it to the git here.

More about multi-linkage issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/886